# Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontNameByRoute()

Tags: magento-1.7

I cloned, by git, a live magento installation, but I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontNameByRoute()
```

I tried some suggestions goggling a bit, but no one of them works.
So, I used `xdebug` and found the variable `$routeName` set as `'install'`. I guess magento doesn't find some file, but I've double checked `etc/local.xml` and the `var` folder permissions.

Does anyone know what magento is looking for otherwise it search for the install route?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the same error, for us, this is because we are loading a non existing category, without `setStoreId()`, then we are trying to `$category->getUrl()`.

This is also because we are trying it in `Xyz_Xyz_Controller_Router`, we have added `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->init();` to fix the problem.